# Subset of $\mathbb{Z}_k^n$ with sufficient local deviations is exponentially large?

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, upper-lower-bounds

Given a non-empty set of vectors $S\subset\mathbb{Z}_k^n$. For every $x_1\in S$ and $i=1,\ldots,n$ there exist $x_2,\ldots,x_k\in S$ such that the vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ are all the same in position $i$ and are all different in any other position. Let $f_k(n)$ denote the minimum possible size of $S$. Does $f_k(n)$ grow exponentially for all $k\geq2$?

For example if $k=2$ then $S$ is closed under adding any vector with all $1$s except for one $0$, the span of which has dimension $n$ for $n$ even and $n-1$ otherwise, giving $f_2(n)\geq2^{n-1}$, which is exponential. A similar argument gives $f_k(2)=k^2$ for all $k\geq2$.

However, for all $k\geq2$ it turns out that $f_k(n)$ is still only $k^2$ for all $2\leq n\leq k+1$. Indeed the span of $(0,1,\ldots,1)$ and $(1,0,1,2,\ldots,k-1)$ fulfills the given criteria.

But I still think $f_k(n)$ grows exponentially for all $k$. Maybe something like $f_k(n)\geq k^{n/k}$ still holds?

Comment: What's the best upper bound you have? Can it be that $$f_k(n) = k+{k \choose 2}\left(2^n-2\right)$$ for each $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$? A set $S$ achieving the RHS is all vectors with at most $2$ distinct elements (of $\mathbb{Z}_k$ appearing amongst the indices). In terms of lower bounds, maybe the polynomial method? But I have absolutely no idea how to apply it, though I haven't thought much.

Comment: @mathworker21 That is a very interesting upper bound construction! But it is definitely not optimal for all $n,k$, for example if $k=2$ and $n$ is odd, or if $k\geq3$ and $3\leq n\leq k+1$. It does show $f_k(n)=O(2^n)$ for all $k\geq2$ though, which improves the trivial bound $f_k(n)\leq k^n$.

Comment: Sorry, completely missed your second-to-last paragraph. Nice! Do you know if $f_k(n)$ is strictly bigger than $k^2$ for $n = k+2$?

Comment: @mathworker21 I think it is, but I'm not sure. At least you can't use the span of two vectors, because there would be two indices with the same ratio of coefficients, at least when $k$ is prime I guess.